# AS2 Add more movieclips to var

Tags: variables, flash, actionscript

This question may be weird, but it's a big problem for me.

```
onClipEvent (load) {
    var ground:MovieClip = _root.bottomground1;
    var grav:Number = 0;
    var gravity:Number = 2;
    var speed:Number = 10;
    var maxJump:Number = -17;
    var touchingGround:Boolean = false;
}
```

So, the thing i want to do is to add more movieclips to var ground, such as

```
var ground:MovieClip = _root.bottomground1,_root.bottomground2...;
```

I tried this also:

```
var ground:MovieClip = _root.bottomground1, MovieClip = _root.bottomground2...;
```

None of it is working. Any reply would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A variable can only have one value :) What you need is an array. Might not be a valid AS2, it's been a while:

Create an array:

```
var groundArray:Array = new Array(_root.bottomground1, _root.bottomground2);
```

OR something like

```
// add objects with instance names bottomground1 to bottomground9
var groundArray:Array = new Array();
for(var i:int = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    groundArray.push(_root[(bottomground + i)]);
}
```

Read from your array:

```
var myGroundMC:MovieClip = groundArray[0] as MovieClip; // first object in array
```

OR

```
// Loop trough all objects and do something
for(var i:int = 0; i < groundArray.length; i++)
{
    var myGroundMC:MovieClip = groundArray[i] as MovieClip;

    // do something with it
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: 
Scene=Scene 1, layer=Ground, frame=4, Line 3 Syntax error.

Comment: So what code is on this line ? Just spotted an error in my code, should be groundArray.push(_root[("bottomground" + i)]);

Comment: Hello! I found out how to make working arrays, but still i can't make that flash recognize them as MovieClips.

var ground:Array = new Array("_root.classicground2", "_root.classicground1", "_root.biggerground1", "_root.bigground1") as MovieClip;

Comment: No, you don't need "" here, this would make an array of strings and you want an array of movieclips, so it should be just var groundArray:Array = new Array(_root.bottomground1, _root.bottomground2);

Comment: I fixed that. There are no errors, but it still doesn't work, i don't know why :/ Download my .FLA: https://www.sendspace.com/file/couaec I hope you could fix this :(